# Tizen native project is not created

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I want to make native app for gear fit2.
but when I create a wearable-2.3.1 native project, it outputs an error.
I received an answer to the same question in the 'Tizen developers'. But it does not address.
Please help me to start the development to Tizen.

### error popup message :

'Creating native project' has encountered a problem.
An internal error occurred during:"Creating native project"
<< Details 
An internal error occurred during: "Creating native project".

### java.lang.NullPointerException

If you need more information, please tell me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is the actual problem there.
But i think below link will help you

https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/sdk-ide/emulator-problem?langredirect=1
they said project name should different with folder's name. It's ide bug.

otherwise, reference below link. 
https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/cli-installer-patch-released

hope you got a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer.

I tried everything to follow all the instructions.
But unfortunately, I was not solved.